# Using Select statement inside of array constructor in PostgresSQL?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'm working with point coordinates in PostGIS and I have a problem. My goal is to generate linestrings by using ST_MakeLine geometry constructor (see snippet 1). Source data is pre-generated ST_MakePoint statements and can contain multiple points (see example from snippet 2). Due that, I have to use ARRAY constructor inside ST_MakeLine geometry constructor.

```
-- snippet 1 (example of geometry contstructor I'm trying to use)

SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeLine(ARRAY[<point_data_here>]),4326)
```

```
-- snippet 2 (data in column, type text)

ST_MakePoint(62.577460, 29.789088), ST_MakePoint(62.577431, 29.788905), ST_MakePoint(62.577109, 29.789399), ST_MakePoint(62.576793, 29.790482)
```

```
-- snippet 3 (this works well, returns geometry as expected)

SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeLine(ARRAY[ST_MakePoint(62.577460, 29.789088), ST_MakePoint(62.577431, 29.788905), ST_MakePoint(62.577109, 29.789399), ST_MakePoint(62.576793, 29.790482)]),4326)
```

My exact question is, how can I embed text data shown in snippet 2 in ARRAY constructor shown in snippet 1? If I do it by manyally copying and pasteing (see snippet 3), there are no problems. But how can I do SELECT statement (data from column which have type of text) inside that ARRAY constructor?

Comment: just to be absolutely sure: that column value is actually a string with those statements, e.g. `'ST_MakePoint(62.577460, 29.789088)'`? lol, now that's a pain in the.

Comment: Yes, it is a text string (concatenated and combined earlier from list of coordinates). Single quotes are used while generating it and type of the column is text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could tediously extract those numbers from the string using PostgreSQLs regex functions, but I suggest to simply add a geometry column and update within a `DO` block using `EXECUTE`:

```
ALTER TABLE <your_table>
  ADD COLUMN geom GEOMETRY(LINESTRING, 4326)
;

DO
  $$
  DECLARE r RECORD;
  BEGIN
    FOR r IN SELECT <id>, <statements> FROM <your_table>
    LOOP
      EXECUTE CONCAT(
        'UPDATE <your_table>
         SET    geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeLine(ARRAY[', r.<statements>, ']), 4326)
         WHERE  <id> = ', r.<id>
      );
    END LOOP;
  END
  $$
;
```

Don't forget to replace all `<>` enclosed identifiers with your actual names.

---

Obviously, the pre-concatenating of *actual SQL statements* is a bad idea. If you can, avoid it; anything is better really, but I suggest to form a valid EWKT string instead, e.g.

```
'SRID=4326;LINESTRING(62.577460 29.789088, 62.577431 29.788905, 62.577109 29.789399, ...)'
```

in that pre-processing step of yours (note that there is no `,` between X and Y coordinates) and

```
SELECT <wkt_string>::GEOMETRY AS geom     -- or ST_GeomFromEWKT(<wkt_string>) AS geom
FROM   <your_table>
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ThingumaBob! I totally agree you line related to pre-concatenating actual statements is a bad idea. But, I was desperate while trying to find workaround. I used your EWKT example to solve this, so huge thanks to you dude! Actually I created function which "reads" coordinates, concatenates those into EWKT string and creates WKB geometry. Pretty much easier to call that function instead of complex query while updating values is table.